# Create another table and columns based on another table data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following table :

Table 1

```
Create  table Table1 (Col1 Varchar2(50) not null, Col2 Varchar2(50), Col3 Varchar2(50));

Insert into Table1 (col1, col2, col3) values 
('RED','aa','11,22,33'),
('Green','bb','33'),
('blue','bb','11,44'), 
('yellow','bb','55,66'), 
('orange','bb','22,33');
```

[image]

Colx_11 will have the value based on Table1, how many records in Table1 for Col3 is having 11 as the value.

Similarly for 22,33 and other values.

Output Table2
[image]

Comment: Need a sql query to get the output shown in Table2

Comment: why is this tagged oracle ? mysql and oracle 2 different databases

Comment: @KoenLostrie Thanks, it was by mistake. I have corrected it now.

Comment: Can column `Col3` contain the same number twice? For example `11,11,22`. If yes, do you count `11` twice or once?

Comment: No duplicate in same column.

Comment: Could you tell which `version` of oracle are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the oracle version is not known i would put my answer with all possibilities,

Because there is not specific pre-defined function available in oracle to split the comma separated records easily we need to use `regular expression` to split it and then count the occurrence.

***Using conditional aggregation (Work with any version > 8i):***

```
select sum(case when split_number = 11 then 1 else 0 end) as col_11
      ,sum(case when split_number = 22 then 1 else 0 end) as col_22
      ,sum(case when split_number = 33 then 1 else 0 end) as col_33
      ,sum(case when split_number = 44 then 1 else 0 end) as col_44
      ,sum(case when split_number = 55 then 1 else 0 end) as col_55
      ,sum(case when split_number = 66 then 1 else 0 end) as col_66
  from table1 t1
  join (select distinct col3,regexp_substr(col3,'[^,]+', 1, level) split_number
         from table1 t2
        connect by regexp_substr(col3, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null) t2
    on t2.col3 = t1.col3;
```

***Using PIVOT and JOIN (Work with any version >= 11g):***

```
select *
  from
(
select split_number
  from table1 t1
  join (select distinct col3,regexp_substr(col3,'[^,]+', 1, level) split_number
         from table1 t2
        connect by regexp_substr(col3, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null) t2
    on t2.col3 = t1.col3
)
pivot
(
 count(*)
 for split_number in ( 11 as col_11
                     , 22 as col_22
                     , 33 as col_33
                     , 44 as col_44
                     , 55 as col_55
                     , 66 as col_66)
);
```

***Using PIVOT and LATERAL (Work with any version >= 12c):***

```
select *
  from
(
select split_number
  from table1 t1,
  lateral (select regexp_substr(col3,'[^,]+', 1, level) split_number
             from dual
           connect by regexp_substr(col3, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null) t2
)
pivot
(
 count(*)
 for split_number in ( 11 as col_11
                     , 22 as col_22
                     , 33 as col_33
                     , 44 as col_44
                     , 55 as col_55
                     , 66 as col_66)
);
```

I would still like to mention here the disadvantage of above queries is mentioning the columns like `col_11` and `col_22`... etc. explicitly and to have this dynamic we would need dynamic SQL or anything with `XML` queries.